# Azure Service Bus: No session available to complete the message with the lock token

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am working with Service Bus Queues in Logic Apps but sometimes when a lot of messages are coming through at a certain time I am starting to get this error while trying to complete the message. It's not related to Message lock lost or Lock Duration, I have looked into other sources online but couldn't find a solid answer to why is this happening and what to do to avoid this completely.

Partitioning may be a solution but I am not 100% sure.

```
Error: No session available to complete the message with the lock token
Failed
```

[image]

Thanks,
Arslan

Answer (score 0):

As per the Connect to Azure Service Bus from Azure logic apps [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus#connector-reference) and as you clearly mentioned that this issue is not because of Message lock lost or lock duration. Maybe the issue could be because of exceeding the session count limit. (1500 unique sessions).

> From a service bus, the Service Bus connector can save up to 1,500 unique sessions at a time to the connector cache, per [Service Bus messaging entity, such as a subscription or topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions). If the session count exceeds this limit, old sessions are removed from the cache. For more information, see [Message sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions).
>
> For other technical details about triggers, actions, and limits, which are described by the connector's Swagger description, review the [connector reference page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/). For more about Azure Service Bus Messaging, see [What is Azure ServiceBus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview)?

Either you can reduce the sessions per time or you can raise a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/cb47c115-7926-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c)

Comment: Thanks for the great response.

I do not think it's happening because of the hard limit or the throttling issues. I am not talking about thousands of messages here only in hundreds 150 max.
Usage of Sessions is my requirement here to process the messages in order, the max number of sessions I observed during this issue was 5-10.